# How to load extension on Edge by Selenium?

Tags: selenium, extension-methods, microsoft-edge

How can I an load extension in Edge with Selenium?

- my extension file is appx file.
- I already worked with loading extensions for chrome (with .crx file) and I wanted to do the same with Edge, but it doesn't work the same.

Chrome example:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();  
options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"));  
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();    
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);  
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Edge:

```
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
```

But "addExtensions" doesn't exist for Edge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import browser extensions in Safari/Edge/IE selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412678/import-browser-extensions-in-safari-edge-ie-selenium)

Comment: Already saw this. It is very old answer, from 2016. Since then, edge have already extension on thier browser.

Comment: I also found on Edge support portal, that on 2016 they didn't create this sideloading yet. So I thougth maybe its ready now on 2018 and someone know how to use it....

Answer (score 0):

For Edge, its a little different. It would be better if you have the unpacked version of extension. So if you own the extension then the solution would work for you. You can try with the below code:

```
const EDGE_DRIVER = require ('selenium-webdriver/edge');
const extension_dir = ["C:\\Users\\divyanshu_juneja\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\\LocalState\\My_Extension"];
const service = new EDGE_DRIVER.ServiceBuilder().setPort(55555).build();
let options = new EDGE_DRIVER.Options();
options.set("extensionPaths", extension_dir);
let driver = EDGE_DRIVER.Driver.createSession(options, service);
driver.get('http:/google.com/');
```

Few things to notice here:

1. The extension is supposed to in that specific path only, just replace your username with mine and replace the My_Extension with the unpacked version of your extension (not the .appx).
2. You need to use `set` function and give the string `extensionPaths` for the driver to load the extension before the browser is started.